# how to create xdbc server using mlgradle in Marklogic?

Tags: marklogic-10, ml-gradle

I am trying create xdbc server using mlgradle. It does for REST/http server but not getting options for xdbc.

```
mlAppName=test-app
mlHost=localhost
mlUsername=admin
mlPassword=test
mlRestPort=8007
mlXdbcport=8009
```

Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create an XML or JSON server config file under your `/src/main/ml-config/servers/` directory with `server-type` set to `xdbc`:

An example JSON:

```
{
    "server-name": "%%NAME%%-xdbc",
    "group-name": "%%GROUP%%",
    "server-type": "xdbc",
    "root": "/",
    "port": %%XDBC_PORT%%,
    "content-database": "%%DATABASE%%",
    "modules-database": "%%MODULES_DATABASE%%"
}
```

An example XML config on the ml-gradle project: https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/blob/master/examples/sample-project/src/main/ml-config/servers/xdbc-server.xml

```
<xdbc-server-properties xmlns="http://marklogic.com/manage">
  <server-name>%%NAME%%-xdbc</server-name>
  <group-name>%%GROUP%%</group-name>
  <server-type>xdbc</server-type>
  <root>/</root>
  <port>%%XDBC_PORT%%</port>
  <content-database>%%DATABASE%%</content-database>
  <modules-database>%%MODULES_DATABASE%%</modules-database>
</xdbc-server-properties>
```

Comment: I created the json file under /src/main/ml-config/servers/xdbc-server.json                but still it does not do anything. I ran "gradle mlDeploye -Penvironment=local"

Comment: Could you please let me know, why is this not working?